# How can you use a function that is defined below its usage?

Tags: javascript

I always thought that `function a(){}` is identical to `a = function(){};`

However, these two snippets behave differently:

```
a();
function a() {
  alert("Booya");
}
```

Prints Booya.

```
a();
a = function() {
  alert("Booya");
}
```

Fails with an exception, which makes sense, since a is really not defined when called.

So - what kind of 'magic' lets the first snippet work, even though `a()` is defined below its point of usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the difference between function declaration and function expression. This difference described well for example [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/).

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript all the declarations are hoisted. Means the **variable can be used before it has been declared** **and function can be used before its declared**.
  It’s JavaScript’s default behaviour to move all the declarations at top of the current script.

But this feature may lead to bugs in application so we use **strict mode directive** to avoid bugs. Strict mode does not allow to use variables without declaration.

more info at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

Answer (score 2):

See this article for an explanation: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

> Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved ("hoisted") invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

No magic, proper coding is required. AFAIK

- document is loaded and parsed, functions are 'loaded'. The the script is being executed. So far no problem _a() _ is found.
- no function is 'maped'. The script si executed line by line. It tries to call *a()* and THEN assign function to a global variable *a*

Answer (score -1):

Functions are defined global. But if you assign a function to a variable, as you do in the second case, the scope rules for variables come into effect: You can not call the function before its variable was defined.

Comment: Functions are not defined global - they are defined within the current scope. Take `function a() { function b() {} }` for example: `b()` is not available outside the `a()`-context. It's not a question about *global* or *not global* it's a question between *declaration stage* and *execution stage*.